# Error installing SP package on Linux Mint 19

Tags: r, spatial

I would like to know if anyone has the solution for the following SP package installation error in Linux Mint 19? Here's the error message.

```
/bin/bash: line 2: g++: command not found
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'sp.so' failed
make: *** [sp.so] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sp’
```

Thanks, Kaio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don’t have the g++ compiler.

Open a terminal window and try

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

The other alternative which includes some common build libraries is

```
sudo apt-get install build-essencial
```

Then try to reinstall the R package.

Comment: Not essentially, I get the same error msg even if I have newest versions of both. Any other ideas?